# How do I tell beta app review to test on a compatible device?

Tags: ios-appstore, testflight

I'm trying to do a TestFlight beta test for an app, but app review keeps rejecting it saying it crashes.

My app has UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities set to limit the devices it can be installed on. It doesn't support the iPad, but the app review team keeps testing it on an iPad, saying it crashes, and rejecting the binary. I've told them the above multiple times, both in the testing notes and when responding to the rejection.

How do I get them to test on a compatible device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All iPhone apps must be able to run on an iPad. If there is not sufficient technology in the iPad, an appropriate message needs to be shown. Your app cannot crash during app review for any reason. Apple may bring out an iPad which meets the device capabilities in the future and you shouldn't have to update your app before it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and beta app review approved the app, though I don't know if it's just a fluke, or they happened to test on a supported device. Has your suggestion consistently worked for you? BTW, to address your last point, if Apple brings out a device that meets the capabilities mentioned in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, the app will automatically work. I won't have to update it. But testing the app on an unsupported device is stupid and doesn't achieve the goal of making sure end-users have a great experience.